# Suppressing a repeated column value in SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am building LINQ to SQL and its run against SQlite database. I need to remove repeating column values from the dataset. Basically the value would be shown for the first row in the dataset and blanked for each subsequent row that had the same value.

I read about using break but I am not sure how to write it up or if it can be used. I read other threads addressing the same issue but was not able to come up with a solution for my scenario.

Should I just retrieve the dataset and suppress them in C# code? 
If so I need help/pointers to do that.

Comment: That it a UI concern.  Since you don't say how you're "showing" the data the answer will vary.  Report?  Grid?  Web Page?

Comment: @D Stanley - Yes it is a report. Using Reportviewer to display data. How can it be done in Reportviewer? Thanks!

Comment: It is MS Reportviewer and I use VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are displaying this data in an SSRS report (.RDLC), set the [`HideDuplicates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa256586.aspx) property of the text box that shows the data to either the name of the dataset or the grouping it's in (to show the value at the start of a new group).

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it is possible by changing a property setting. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the result and set a local variable of

```
string lastValue = null;
foreach(var row in rows)
{
   if(lastValue == row.SomeColumn)
   {
      row.SomeColumn = null;
   }
   else
   {
     lastValue = row.SomeColumn
   }
}
```

Probably others ways, but hard to say without more context of what you have so far.

Comment: Just my opinion, but this should be done in the UI, not in the underlying data.

Comment: If it's an MVC page, then this code can be placed in the UI.  It could also be placed in the ViewModel mapping as well if it is a ViewModel specific to the scenarios where this is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Linq to get the values from your table using the Distinct Method?